# Tomcat: Is Restart only solution to memory leak due to Threadlocal?

Tags: tomcat

We are using apache-tomcat-8.0.20 in production environment.

Our application (Japha) got crashed suddenly and server got shut down automatically due to following error:

```
25-Nov-2015 05:20:37.311 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [Japha] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2472eccc]) and a value of type [com.sun.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl] (value [com.sun.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl@24d1f33]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Nov-2015 05:20:37.311 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [Japha] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1@73b0e605d]) and a value of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator[]] (value [[Lcom.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator;@2d42463a5b]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

And in end it stopped all connectors

```
25-Nov-2015 05:20:37.327 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [Japha] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.ws.api.client.ServiceInterceptorFactory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.ws.api.client.ServiceInterceptorFactory$1@434ba48d]) and a value of type [java.util.HashSet] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Nov-2015 05:20:37.356 INFO [Thread-7] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Nov-2015 05:20:37.453 INFO [Thread-7] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
25-Nov-2015 05:20:37.462 INFO [Thread-7] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Nov-2015 05:20:37.464 INFO [Thread-7] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

No Customer activity is recorded in this time period by end user as it was early morning. We simply restarted the server and all is running fine. But is restart best solution to this? or will this problem occur again?

Comment: Do you restart the tomcat when you redeploy your application? Or do you just redeploy the app without restarting tomcat? 

Related to memory leaks with tomcat I suggest you to read this page from the Apache Wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection

Comment: Are these the first errors in the logs? These look like errors when trying to stop/undeploy the app, as if something else happened first

Answer (score 0):

Because you restart Tomcat on each redeploy your memory leak is not caused by a classloader leak of Tomcats WebappClassLoader which is most common cause for memory leaks related to Tomcat. Therefore you could ignore the link I posted in the comment.

Instead you should add the VM parameter `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` so a heap dump is created when an OutOfMemoryError occurs. When this happens again, you could open the heap dump with a heap dump analyzer like [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) . There you could do further investigation in order to find the leak cause. You could e.g. look into the dominator tree in order to find the objects that hold the most amount of memory trough references. If you've found something suspiciously you could post a screenshot from Eclipse MAT here.

If you don't want to wait until an OutOfMemoryError occurs again, then you could also manually create a heapdump after the application was running for a while and analyse it.